# Mongo DB like search with count is very slow on 50 million collection data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

In my application, I have a collection of 50 million data. I am using like search and then count the results on a particular field(i.e Patientfirstname). I also created an index on the Patientfirstname field it improved the performance but still it is taking a lot of time.

db.patients.find({"Patientfirstname":{"$regex":"Testuser"}}).count() without index **40** sec

db.patients.find({"Patientfirstname":{"$regex":"Testuser"}}).count() after adding index on the Patientfirstname field **31** sec

```
db.patients.find({"Patientfirstname":{"$regex":"Testuser"}}).count()
```

I tried with a different approach (aggregate) but still, response is very slow

```
 db.patients.aggregate.([{$match:{"Patientfirstname":{"$regex":"Testuser"}}},
{$project:{"Patientfirstname":1,"_id":1}},
{$group : {_id:"$Patientfirstname", count:{$sum:1}}},
{$sort:{"count":-1}} ])
```

this query also takes the same to time fetch the results 31 sec

another approach was tried but the results are not correct

select only the field from the entire collection and then apply like search and count and result.

```
db.patients.find({},{Patientfirstname:1,_id:1}).count({"Patientfirstname":{"$regex":"Testuser"}})
```

applying a filter in the count is not working, entire collection count is displayed
Please help in this query to fetch results faster.Thanks in advance

Comment: Searches by regular expressions are generally slow, a normal index does not help. You may consider [Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)

Comment: See [$regex and Index Use](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use). Also, you can see how the index is applied on the query filter using the `explain()` method. In general, also know about: [Indexing and Query Selectivity](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-queries-that-ensure-selectivity/).

Answer (score 4):

So here is the deal:

As rightly pointed in the comments, $regex is an operator that would not perform well with or without indexes. Here is the reason why:

Queries without indexes are slow because they executed using COLLSCAN - which is essentially iteration of the whole 50 Million documents on the disk one-by-one, filtering data and returning only the ones that match. Disks being an inherently slow piece of hardware does not help the situation either.

Now, When indexed - MongoDB creates a B-Tree in the RAM. And $regex operator being not very selective in nature, it forces a complete Tree Scan (as compared to a reduced / partial tree scan in case of equalities or ranges) in the index b-tree - which is as bad as a Collection Scan itself. The only reason you get a benefit on 9 seconds is because this Tree Scan occurs in the RAM and not the disk.

Having said that, there are a few alternatives to it:

1. Optimize your $regex. From the [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#behavior) itself:

> For case sensitive regular expression queries, if an index exists for the field, then MongoDB matches the regular expression against the values in the index, which can be faster than a collection scan. Further optimization can occur if the regular expression is a "prefix expression", which means that all potential matches start with the same string. This allows MongoDB to construct a "range" from that prefix and only match against those values from the index that fall within that range.

> A regular expression is a "prefix expression" if it starts with a caret (^) or a left anchor (\A), followed by a string of simple symbols. For example, the regex /^abc.*/ will be optimized by matching only against the values from the index that start with abc.

> Additionally, while /^a/, /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ match equivalent strings, they have different performance characteristics. All of these expressions use an index if an appropriate index exists; however, /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ are slower. /^a/ can stop scanning after matching the prefix.

Case insensitive regular expression queries generally cannot use indexes effectively. The $regex implementation is not collation-aware and is unable to utilize case-insensitive indexes.

2. Create a [Text Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) - This would tokenize your text string and enable faster text based searches
3. If you are deployed on MongoDB Atlas - Then you can use [Atlas Search](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search/tutorial/) which is a Lucene based Text Search Engine (Works *almost* like elasticsearch on steroids). This offers significantly greater performance and functionalities like fuzzy text search, text automcomplete etc.